# Blade and Soul gold?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, spam

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253565/where-to-buy-blade-and-soul-gold) (new user) asks for the best place to buy gold for Blade & Soul. In a couple of minutes, an answer has come for a specific site (also new user, different one). It smells like spam to me. Is it? How to deal with this smarter kind of spam?

Comment: It's either seed question for spam, or a user asking for a thing we don't support.

Comment: It's spam.  Flag as such, and let the system burn it.